# Hibernate mapping - mismatch between columns

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

After migrating from Hibernate 3.2.7.ga to 5.0.4.Final I am getting the following error when building the SessionFactory:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK6ysnihr27dq6030taryppmjw3:CABLE [BOARD_1_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Board [JOINT_ID,NAIL_INDEX])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1889)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1809)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
```

The columns mentioned in the error message (JOINT_ID,NAIL_INDEX) have nothing to do with the primary key of Board. The primary key of Board is BOARD_ID. NAIL_INDEX is not even mentioned in the Board.hbm.xml.

Cable.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "classpath:hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.oxi.beans">
  <joined-subclass extends="com.oxi.beans.AbstractEntity" name="Cable" table="CABLE">
    <key column="CABLE_ID"/>
    <property name="tag" type="com.oxi.EscapedString"/>
    <many-to-one class="Board" column="BOARD_1_ID" name="board1"/>
    <many-to-one class="Board" column="BOARD_2_ID" name="board2"/>
  </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Board.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "classpath:hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.oxi.beans">
  <joined-subclass extends="com.oxi.beans.AbstractEntity" name="Board">
    <key column="BOARD_ID"/>
    <property length="100" name="label" type="com.oxi.EscapedString"/>
    <property name="unique" type="boolean"/>
    <property name="standard" type="boolean"/>
    <many-to-one class="Body" column="BODY_ID" name="body"/>
    <many-to-one class="Joint" column="JOINT_ID" name="joint"/>
    <many-to-one class="BoardInstance" column="BOARD_INSTANCE_ID" fetch="join" name="boardInstance"/>
    <map name="propertyValues" table="PROPERTY_VALUE">
      <key column="ENTITY_ID"/>
      <map-key column="PROPERTY_ID" type="long"/>
      <element column="PROPERTY_VALUE" type="com.oxi.EscapedString"/>
    </map>
    <many-to-one class="BoardType" column="BOARD_TYPE_ID" name="type"/>
  </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The keys definition in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE CABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_H_F1 FOREIGN KEY (BOARD_1_ID) REFERENCES BOARD (BOARD_ID);
ALTER TABLE CABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_H_F2 FOREIGN KEY (BOARD_2_ID) REFERENCES BOARD (BOARD_ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_H_F1 ON CABLE (BOARD_1_ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_H_F2 ON CABLE (BOARD_2_ID);
```

Before the migration to Hibernate 5 I was using configuration.setEntityResolver to make sure the dtd for the mapping files is taken from the classpath. In Hibernate 5 I didn't find a way to specify a custom EntityResolver, so I did not use one. This might be a reason why the mappings are not interpreted correctly but the error does not give hints in this direction.